# How do I edit the file content through chef recipe?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have create a file through chef recipe. The codes are below.

```
execute "helloworld.txt" do
  command "mkdir /etc/#{node['jboss']['user']}"
  not_if { ::File.exists?("/etc/#{node['jboss']['user']}")}
end

file "/etc/jboss-as/helloworld.txt" do
   owner 'user'
   group 'user'
   mode 0755
   action :create_if_missing
end

template "/etc/jboss-as/helloworld.txt" do
  source "helloworld.txt.erb"
end
```

My helloworld.txt file content below:

```
TESTING 
Hello World 
Hello Winnie 
Hello Everyone 
Hello Boy
```

I want to edit Hello Boy to Hello Girl using code to edit the command above, what command should I use and I need to do? I do not want to just change content directly from the helloworld.txt.

Please comment below to show your solution. Thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

You've been asking a long series of very basic questions about Chef. I would highly encourage you to read through some of the tutorials and online training materials rather than asking SO to effectively do your job for you.

That said, what you want is two resources. First is a directory resource to create the needed directory:

```
directory "/etc/#{node['jboss']['user']}" do
  user node['jboss']['user']
  mode '755'
end
```

This will create the required directory and ensure the owner and mode match what is requested. This is safer than using mkdir as that will not be convergent in all cases (wouldn't correct the owner/mode is changed for example).

After that you want to create the file. There are 4 main options in Chef for that, `file`, `cookbook_file`, `template`, and `remote_file`. All four of these are related and share the same core options (`user`, `group`, `mode`) but get the file content from a different place.

`file` is for writing content generated by your recipe code. This is mostly convenient for writing out things like empty files (the default), or JSON/Yaml data generated by the recipe.

`cookbook_file` copies file content verbatim from the `files/` section of the cookbook. This is useful for binary files like license keys which you don't want to modify, just transfer to the target system as is.

`template` is similar to `cookbook_file` but runs the content through the Erb templating language before writing it out. This allows dynamic content based on things like node attributes or search queries.

`remote_file` downloads the file content from a provided URL instead of getting it from the Chef Server.

In this case it seems like a `template` is probably what you want:

```
template "/etc/#{node['jboss']['user']}/helloworld.txt" do
  user node['jboss']['user']
  mode '644'
  source 'helloworld.txt.erb'
end
```

Comment: OP asked how to alter/append a file.. but this template lets you create a file with a source.. Is there a way to alter a file or append something in the end of the file?

Comment: Don't ask new questions in the comments of something from a year ago.